# heroku static resources nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I hosted my nodejs project on heroku and it deployed successfully,but i am unable to load any static resources from public or node_modules folder.Tried some hacks of putting some lines of code in app.js and other but nothing works.Tried process.cwd() approach too ,but failed. I have done this for the first time.Please Help.

```
    var createError = require('http-errors');
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
    var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
    var app = express();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
    // view engine setup
    app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(process.env.PWD, 'node_modules')));
    app.use('/jsonfiles', express.static(path.join(process.env.PWD, 'jsonfiles')));
    app.set('views', path.join(process.env.PWD, 'views'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(process.env.PWD, 'public')));

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());


    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/users', usersRouter);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      next(createError(404));
    });
    http.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, function() {
        console.log('listening on *:8000');
    });



    // error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Are you able to share the error you get in the server logs? There are a lot of unnecessary lines of code in your application entry point, repetitive code and errors. As you mentioned static files, and as an example, you seem to use multiple static assets directories. `/scripts` and `/jsonfiles` are the virtual paths served from `node_modules` and `jsonfiles`.  `public` is the other directory holding static files. My question is, do you really have multiple static directories or do you have a specific directory for static files?

Comment: Additionally, and most importantly, you are passing the `process.env.PWD` property that returns an object inside the `path.join` method; you should only pass strings inside that method and no objects.

Comment: I Have multiple static directories to serve. Also the process.env.PWD approach is what i got from stackoverflow when i typed this question. (and hence i tried it,but failed).

Comment: Are you still dealing with this issue?

Comment: I uploaded it on evennode instead of heroku... and it is up and running smooth. Also the repetitive code is removed, i gave up on heroku after so many trials!